# How do I find out why a answer was deleted?

Tags: support

I am new and have no clue why my answer was deleted. It does not match anything in the list of reasons. If I can't fix this, I may be wasting my time here.

If spoofing a MAC address is deemed illegal, I disagree. I am telling the router I(the person that logged in) am still here, just on different hardware. The method is explained on wikipedia.

Answer (score 6):

Your answer was flagged as "spam" by another user and while this claim is probably a little over the top I deleted it for two reasons:

- You're using the answer to request more information (*Are you trying to connect to captive portals...*). This does not belong to the answer section but should be done using comments.
- The answer is not specific to the question. While you drop the key word and a link you leave any explanation as to why and how this works completely aside.

In retrospect I take it that deletion may have been a bit too harsh and undeserved. I will undelete the question if you intend to improve it with regard to the mentioned issues. It is my fault that I did not provide an explanation at that time of handling said flag and I apoligize for that. From your other answers I think that you're not wasting your time here but that your contributions are and will be valued. Hope to see you around.

Please check the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour), the [helpcenter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help), and the [guide to good answers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer):

> **Answer the question**
>
> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.
>
> **Provide context for links**
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: I have the impression that, most of the time, your chances are much better in other SE sites. Here, (some) moderators are artificially 'tough' and disrespectful on their comments, on questions and on answers. Here, hundreds of hollow unfiltered q&a, some of them technically incorrect, wasting reader time, however, some valid ones are flagged or negatively commented. Moderators should have a more didactic vs police (or censorship) position. If it's a valid question but incorrectly worded, just fix it! (Instead of flag/delete).

Comment: *moderators are artificially 'tough' and disrespectful* moderators are expected to follow the *be nice* policy, same as all users. In the sense of leading by example and being patient, fair, impartial, and respecting to the users one might even expect outstanding behaviour of the moderators. While this is what we all strive for, be reminded that moderators are mere humans too. If you have certain incidents in mind, feel free to contact us to resolve the issue. We're certainly not beyond doubt but willing to improve.

Comment: *hundreds of hollow unfiltered q&a, some of them technically incorrect* moderators are not supposed to scan all 10k questions and assess their quality. The idea of StackExchange is that the site is community moderated and numerous tools are available to all users based on reputation to help the moderation (including voting, flagging, editing, commenting). Moderators are supposed to handle the extreme cases - such as those flagged by all users. So, if you come up with incorrect A's use your tools, comment, vote, or flag.

Comment: *If it's a valid question but incorrectly worded, just fix it!* Editing has its limits, see [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/editing), i.e. edits that change the original post to the extend that the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost are undesirable. Which is exactly why some questions are put on hold to be edited by the original poster and receive comments to ask for additional input and/or suggestions for edits.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your and others voluntary job. Sometimes moderators are fast in flag and others looks like they ignore some clear violations. Moderator actions are (almost) anonymous however user actions are easy to identify: I don't want to taint my reputation as a 'bad guy', I'm sure others feel the same way.